# Need to convert the ssh output to dictionary in pyton

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert the following to a dictionary:

My output from paramiko ssh output. Also i have pasted my error also. I need to convert dictionary and get info this  HBA Port WWN > Link Error Statistics >Link Failure Count

```
HBA Port WWN: 2100f4e9d4583286
        Port Mode: Target
        Port ID: 10500
        Link Error Statistics:
                Link Failure Count: 1
                Loss of Sync Count: 0
                Loss of Signal Count: 0
        Fabric Port NPIV Support: Supported
        NPIV port list:
          Virtual Port1:
                Node WWN: 51c5a0b27968bf2e
                Port WWN: 51c5a0b27968bf2f
                Port Status: enabled

HBA Port WWN: 2100f4e9d4583287
        Port Mode: Target
        Port ID: 10500
        Link Error Statistics:
                Link Failure Count: 1
                Loss of Sync Count: 0
                Loss of Signal Count: 0
        Fabric Port NPIV Support: Supported
        FW Supported Max NPIV Ports: 254
        NPIV port list:
          Virtual Port1:
                Node WWN: 51c5a0b27968bf2e
                Port WWN: 51c5a0b27968bf31
                Port Status: enabled
```

I have already tried to do the following:

```
import paramiko
import sys
import time


hostname = 'hostname'
fcinfo = 'fcinfo hba-port -l'


c_cred = open("hostlist.csv","r")

for i in c_cred.readlines():
    line=i.strip()
    ls =line.split(",")
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect("%s"%ls[0],port =22, username = "%s"%ls[1], password="%s"%ls[2])
    channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
    out = channel.recv(9999)
    channel.send('su -\n')
    channel.send('wdc\n')
    channel.send(fcinfo+'\n')
    while not channel.recv_ready():
        time.sleep(3)
    out = channel.recv(9999)
    sorted_string=((out.decode("ascii")).split('\n',13)[-1])
    print(sorted_string)
    for line in sorted_string:
        key, val = line.split(":")
        d[key] = val
    print (d)
    ssh.close()
c_cred.close()
```

`sorted_string=((out.decode("ascii")).split('\n',13)[-1])` output faced above

getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vv.py", line 30, in <module>
    key, value = line.split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I need to convert dictionary and get info this
`HBA Port WWN > Link Error Statistics >Link Failure Count`

Comment: Maybe those lines are empty, try printing them to see.

Comment: we have data. this is my data
HBA Port WWN: 2100f4e9d4583286
                Invalid Tx Word Count: 0
                Invalid CRC Count: 0
                        Invalid Tx Word Count: 0
                        Invalid CRC Count: 0
HBA Port WWN: 2100f4e9d4583287
                Invalid Tx Word Count: 0
                Invalid CRC Count: 0
                        Invalid Tx Word Count: 0
                        Invalid CRC Count: 0

Comment: So in the data there is an empty line after the Port status line.